# SQL developer - procedure just for a session

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

Is it possible to create a bunch of procedures just for the SQL developer session, so when the session ends the procedures are deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing you can do is defining procedures in anonymous blocks, for example:

```
Declare
    val number;
    Procedure P1(abc in number, def out number) is
    begin
         def := abc*abc;
    end;
begin
    For i in 1..10 loop
    P1(i,val);
    dbms_output.put_line(val);
    End loop;
end;
/
```

Another feature is defining PL/SQL functions for a single SQL call in 12c.

[Using a PL/SQL Function in the WITH Clause](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABJFIDC)

For example:

```
WITH
 FUNCTION get_domain(url VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
   pos BINARY_INTEGER;
   len BINARY_INTEGER;
 BEGIN
   pos := INSTR(url, 'www.');
   len := INSTR(SUBSTR(url, pos + 4), '.') - 1;
   RETURN SUBSTR(url, pos + 4, len);
 END;
SELECT DISTINCT get_domain(catalog_url)
  FROM product_information;
/
```

Comment: I was hoping that this would be available in the start up script that is automatically loaded on connection

Comment: @Ed Heal Well, there is no such thing as "temporary" procedure in Oracle databases. So if you use a startup script, and let's say you manage to run a logoff script as well when you are finished, you would be still creating regular procedures available for other sessions as well.

Comment: @EdHeal: Maybe either the "Snippets" feature or the templates (preferences - database - SQL editor code templates) could sort of work for you (SQL templates get you sort of aliases that you can expand with code completion).

Comment: @Mat - Thanks for the SQL snippet feature - will give it a go as it might fulfil my requirements